# In Excel execute embedded .exe object

Tags: excel, call, execution, vba

I have inserted an object into Excel. This object is an exe (a console application).

I can call the application by double clicking on it. However, I need to call it with parameters (namely the file path of the document it is being called by). How do I call this exe with parameters?

Comment: is it possible to import .exe in Excel file? I can't do it on my local computer. :)

Comment: @Miki Yeah. Insert and object and get the exe from file.

Comment: Nice, I learned today. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import .exe to Excel with these steps:

1. Insert - Object
2. Select tab: Create from File
3. Browse for exe file
4. Check on "Display as icon"

then you can write VBA subroutine/macro like (I used rectangle shaped object to execute macro by clicking it):

```
Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oo As OLEObject

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set oo = ws.OLEObjects("Object 1")

    oo.Verb xlVerbPrimary

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

The OP asked for a way of including parameters, which doesn't seem to be possible with the accepted solution. I implemented this a different way. This code extracts the file to the workbook's directory and then executes it.

```
Sub saveAndRunFileExample()
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).Copy
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(ActiveWorkbook.Path).Self.InvokeVerb "Paste"
    Call Shell(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\example.exe --parameter", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```